# Removing Zeros from decimal place if they are preceding - PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to format some values when I retrieve them from the database.

Some of the values look like this -

```
Values
121.000
0.170
12.500
12.425
0.890
```

Here is what I want them to look like -

```
Values
121
.17
12.5
12.425
.89
```

I have searched and searched for a solution but I can only seem to find the answer to one or the other, I need this to work dynamically in one function.

I have tried casting the values to a FloatVal but this doesn't work on 100% of the values.

Please could anyone advise?

Any more info needed please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way:

```
$val = ltrim(rtrim($num, '.0'), '0');
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/438113). Actually, `rtrim` here is only to convert `121.0` into `121`, preceding zero is, apparently, dropped with `ltrim`.

Comment: Worked beautifully.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = '0.9';
echo (substr($value, 0, 2) == '0.' ? substr($value, 1) : $value);
```